# Silverstripe Images Has Many

Tags: php, image, oop, relationship, silverstripe

I'm quite new to Silverstripe and have been playing around with the CMS.

At the moment I'm stuck... I'm trying to add a `$has_many` relationship between a DataObject and Images.

I'm finding the documentation on doing something like this quite vague? I know that when you want to add a relationship between two DataObjects you need to add a `$many_many` and `$belongs_many_many` relationship but how would I do this with images?

I tried adding images to a `$has_many` and simply using an upload field but this only causes an error. I also tried keeping the images in `$has_one` and increasing the upload field `setAllowedMaxFileNumber` to 10 but this only saves 1 image.

Any help in this regard would greatly be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Incase anyone wants to see the code here is a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jZsB7y6b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to many_many image, or have an [intermediary object that facilitates images](http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-has-many).

This is due to the way that SilverStripe stores a models relationships.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks!